# Calculate correlations and write to a dataframe

Tags: r, correlation

I'm trying to loop through a data frame and calculate correlation for each observation of x,y and store this is a new frame.

The sub_dat file has columns for date, sulfate, nitrate, ID

```
for (s in sub_dat$ID) {
    corrData <- rbind(cor(sub_dat$sulfate, sub_dat$nitrate))

}

corrData
```

All I get back is a single value rather than a matrix.  I've already removed NA's and I'm getting no error when I debug.  Any ideas?

Comment: Some advice: take a moment and think about how your code inside the `for` loop is supposed to change each time through. You ought to be using the variable `s` somewhere for that purpose; have you? Next take some time to play with `rbind`; how many arguments does it take? Does it make sense to rbind a single object? What happens when you rbind different kinds of objects (data frames, vectors, single values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your data looks like, but I'm going to assume something like this:

```
             x           y group
1   0.08474419  0.16459807     1
2  -0.52390488 -0.52922622     1
3   0.12789339 -0.37239925     1
4  -0.49442433 -0.51763038     1
5   0.22440165 -0.73524373     1
6  -0.13219889  0.06979758     2
7   2.60532503  1.15088422     2
8   0.49880770  0.73113421     2
9   0.05612694  0.44701820     2
10  0.29456281  0.76804105     2
```

Using `library(dplyr)` you can do something like `df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(corr = cor(x, y))`

Output:

```
      group      corr
1     1          0.2093626
2     2          0.8392375
```